# Will there be any performance or quality issues if we use lambda expression in foreach loop?

Tags: performance, linq, coding-style, lambda

I have a piece of code as below -

```
    var serviceResponseItems = new List<ServiceResponseItems>();
    foreach (var item in serviceResponse.SomeItems.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Id) && x.Id.Trim().Length > 0).ToList())
            {
                var responseViewItem = new ResponseViewItem
                {
                    Description = item.ItemDescriptionCode.Trim(),
                    SummaryActivityDate = item.SummaryActivityDate
                };

                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item.Amount))
                {
                    responseViewItem.Amount = Convert.ToDouble(item.Amount.Trim());
                }

                serviceResponseItems.Add(responseViewItem);
            }
        }
```

As you can see, the foreach loop source is a lambda expression. I'm trying to find out areas for improving my code quality across the application.

Can someone suggest if this kind of foreach loop is actually better in terms of performance/quality/standards.

IMO, an alternative to this could be to declare a variable that stores the lambda expression's result and use that variable as part of foreach declaration.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of performance, there is no penalty for having the expression inside the foreach statement. The lambda expression will only be evaluated once at the beginning of the loop.

In terms of quality, in my opinion it is more readable to have the expression outside the foreach statement. This also makes it clearer which items are being iterated over. For example:

```
var itemsWithValidIds = serviceResponse.SomeItems.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Id) &&
                                                        x.Id.Trim().Length > 0);
foreach (var item in itemsWithValidIds)
        {
        ...
```

Comment: I was expecting the same, but was not sure. Thanks for clarifying.